# How to make an other web app can login with wordpress authentication?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I creating an app right now using asp.net mvc 5. My client told me they have a main system created using wordpress. and our new app must be login/auth using that wordpress user or authentication.

this is the schema :

1. user open our new app, and click login button
2. system redirect to "oauth" of main system using wordpress
3. user fill username/email and password. after that submit login
4. main system redirect to new system with token
5. new system verified token and login success on new system

sorry I new with wordpress, i couldnt find any plugins to do it.

How to make an other web app can login with wordpress authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not a platform for SSO, and do not include any API to support such a use case. You can develop a JSON end point to validate users, but the work flow you describe will probably not match it.